# SQLite JDBC ClassNotFoundException during jar execution

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, executable-jar

I'm here to solve my problem with JDBC. I want to build a CRUD app with java and SQLite. I have completed my project with NetBeans IDE. Everything is running very well but the problem is when I generate jar of my project then "ClassNotFoundException" occurs. I need to build a jar and work independently with my app in command line.
So, how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: More info would be helpfull. For exampe wich class in not found, and where it is used in the code.

Answer (score -1):

you surely got the JDBC jar, but do you miss the mysql-connector or SQLite JDBC jar?

I think this is the main issue.

After you added all the library you need, please specify the classpath for those libraries

Comment: I don't see why you have to downvote me. This is the main solution for how the classnotfoundexception is solved.
1. mysql-connector, 2. CLASSPATH definition